# Can't add a reference to EntityFramework in my unit test project

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a new project happily using Entity Framework 5. After I added the edmx to the solution, it added a reference to EntityFramework version 5.

I created a unit test project, and I need to use something from the EntityFramework library. However, there is no reference to EntityFramework. When I go to Add Reference, I cannot find it anywhere in the list.

I've checked and my unit test is referencing .NET 4.5. Any idea why I can't add the reference?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove all the entries you have made to the web.config file. Just Right Click on your project name in the solution, Click on Manage Nuget Packages On your left hand Click on Online and on the right hand just put Entity Framework in the search box. Click on Install

this will do all the things automatically for you.

Answer is taken from: [EntityFramework 5 Install fails in VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825525/entityframework-5-install-fails-in-vs-2012)

Comment: Thanks. I'm unaccustomed to using NuGet for things that I'd have expected to come preinstalled!

Comment: Thank you sir!! .. you are a live saver

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with a new application. I opened the Package Manager Console and used `install-package EntityFramework`, which installed version 6 without issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just Adding **System.Data.Entity** might not enough;

because by this you are trying to **referencing** something that has not been installed yet.

this issue can be resolved by installing **EntityFramework**.

So to do this :

- Go to **Solution Explorer**
- **Right Click** on Your Project Name
- Select **"Manage NuGet packages"**

[image: Install Entity Framework]

- Now Install the Entity Framework.

[image: Nuget Application Manager]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to "System.Data.Entity" dll at References folder of your Unit Test project.

Comment: I found that not being enough.